# scanf. Работа с числами

Tags: c, scanf

Есть такой код:

```
int a, b;
scanf("%d/%d", &a, &b);
print("%d/%d", a, b);
```

Не могу понять, почему в случае ввода `10/5` я получаю на выходе как и положено `10/5`, а в случае ввода `10.3/5` получаю `10/32766`. Что происходит, когда scanf встречает число типа float, но спецификатор формата у меня указан `%d`? Разве он не должен "отсекать" всю часть после запятой и переходить к поиску другого спецификатора, который указан в строке `scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);`?

Comment: Сталкиваясь с `.` там, где должен быть `/`, функция останавливается в состоянии ошибки чтения и возвращает только одно считанное число.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Функция scanf возвращает количество значений, которое ей удалось считать [scanf](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=scanf&category=3&russian=0)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    int scanf_result = scanf("%d/%d", &a, &b);
    printf("%d/%d\n", a, b);
    printf("scanf result: %d\n", scanf_result);
}
```

Иными словами в случае если вы подаете 10.3/5, то scanf вернет 1, что значит, что правильно удалось считать лишь переменную 'a', а в других лежит мусор

Comment: Получается, спецификатор `%d` считывает число `10`, встречает `.`, прерывает дальнейшее считывание строки и записывает в переменную `a` только число `10`, верно?

Comment: scanf ожидает встретить посли числа / но стречает . и останавливает чтение

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере вся загвоздка в символе '/' который стоит у вас между спецификаторами %d. Уберите его и всё будет происходить так как вы хотите. scanf абсолютно безразличен к пробельному символу и к их количеству ставите ли вы '\n' после каждого числа или в конце разделив числа пробелами, но '/' он ждёт именно там где вы его указали. Вместо этого он получает точку и дальше происходит то что сказали тут до меня другие участники. Это же относится и к любым другим символам. Как указываете в scanf точно так же должно быть и введено.
Для убедительности можно поэкспериментировать со
следующим кодом:

```
    int x, y, z;
    z=scanf(" %d.%d",&x,&y);
    printf("%d.%d scanf=%d\n",x,y,z) ;
```